# Cartoon with a dead lady riding a ghost western cart towards a bad guy

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

All I remember is that close to the end of the episode (whatever cartoon it was) a ghostly western cart ridden by a dead lady comes and I think kills or at least scares a bad guy. I think I saw this cartoon on Cartoon Network in the '90s or early 2000s. I think there also was a treasure involved in the story... Something tells me it was *Jonny Quest*, but I couldn't find the episode... I thought it might have been another cartoon...

Comment: Is this a cart like in a "cart and buggy"? A stagewagon? A minecart?

Comment: Hm... Vague memories... I think it was more like a stagewagon from the Wild West

Comment: I believe the term is usually stagecoach instead of stagewagon.   a horse-drawn coach that formerly traveled regularly over a fixed route with passengers, parcels, etc.  https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stagecoach

Comment: Another possibility is he meant a covered wagon... A wagon typically used by a family to travel to new places in the old west.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also searching for this episode for ages. It is called "[The Ballad of Belle Bonnet](http://questfan.com/Page/The_Ballad_of_Belle_Bonnet.html)" from *The Real adventures of Johnny Quest*. Damn, that episode was scary back in the day.

[image: Image of Bonnie and her stagecoach manifesting]

> The next morning, Ames explains that Belle was going to rob to get the money, but had unexpected competition from other thieves. The Indians assumed she simply took the gold and headed east, but Jonny insists that hers is the ghost in the cavern. The team descend, and Jonny and Hadji find the crashed coach and treasure chest full of gold, bringing it to the surface via inflatables. They find that Race and Dr. Quest are missing; Rawlings emerges from the shadow with a shotgun ready. The ghostly visions then appear as the treasure chest spills out and mesmerizes Rawlings. The ghostly stage coach tramples him; Jonny and Hadji find him dead with no visible markings. Belle Bonnet appears a final time to remind them that the gold is for the children.

Comment: Yes, that's it! But I can't find the "accept answer" button on my phone... :(... Indeed it was scary back in the day.

Comment: Sorry, I was logged in with another account. I have now accepted the answer.